# WebSocket shim error with Webpack

Tags: websocket, webpack

I'm having trouble creating a WebSocket object on a webpack project. When I call `new WebSocket("")` it appears as though I get back the constructor as opposed to a new object of that constructor. I have a simple web page that does not use webpack and there everything works fine. Stepping through the working version with the Chrome debugger looks like this:

[image: working]

I cannot step into the `WebSocket` constructor, it just jumps to the next line. Now with my webpacked app it does step into the constructor where I see this:

[image: webpack shim]

and upon stepping out I see this:

[image]

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong here, how can I fix this? The app is not to be hosted by a webpack server, I'm only using webpack for packaging. All of this is on Chrome on OSX; below is my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
//    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
//    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/turborabbit'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    }]
  }
};
```

EDIT:

The module I'm importing and having trouble with is `rserve`. I have a workaround which is the ugliest thing I have ever done. The module only uses underscore and websocket in the offending file; I have overridden the require call for the module using `imports-loader` and injected underscore via the `ProvidePlugin`. This is the relevant portion of webpack config:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    '_': 'underscore'
  })
],
module: {
  loaders: [{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loaders: ['imports', 'react-hot', 'babel'],
    include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
  }]
}
```

And I load the module as follows:

```
var Rserve = require ('imports?require=>(function(x){return(x==="ws"?global.WebSocket:_);})!rserve');
```

I sincerely hope there's a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a better solution by aliasing `ws` in webpack and making a shim that simply returns `WebSocket`. Relevant portion of webpack.config:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    ws: path.resolve ('./') + '/src/shim/ws.js'
  }
}
```

and in src/shim/ws.js:

```
module.exports = WebSocket || MozWebSocket;
```